# Resolve generic service in a runtime by Type

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

I want to apply some logic to process every Response Object in my controllers

With that being said I created FilterAttribute and overridden OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)

Inside this method I need to apply some custom logic **based on type of response object**

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
{            
        if(context.Result != null && context.Result is ObjectResult result)
        {
            var type = result.GetType();

            var validator = _serviceProvider.GetService<IValidator<type>>();

            if (validator != null)
            {
                validator.Validate(result);
            }
        }

        base.OnActionExecuted(context);
}
```

this is where the problem is

**_serviceProvider.GetService<IValidator < Some Type > >();**

The generic param should be known by compilation time. Any ideas how to achieve that?

Comment: do you have `IValidator`

Comment: @DanielA.White yes, but IValidator is generic and I should gibve the type as a generic param

Comment: Maybe you need [`MakeGenericType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.makegenerictype?view=net-6.0) as the compiler can't know what `result.GetType()` is going to return at runtime?

Comment: We don't know what type `_serviceProvider` is. Bus assuming it's the ASP.NET Core default one, there is a non generic [`GetService`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider.getservice?view=net-6.0) method taking a type as parameter, with @stuartd comment and a base non generic interface, you might be able to work something out

Comment: it looks a bit strange to me your goal. Using the type as discriminator will result in a hard-to-solve problem when you have two or more types equal (e.g. string). Moreover, the type will have some other purpose in the validation? I mean, I'd create my own validation provider using a custom key (even a type, if you are sure there are no  collisions). However, the interface should IValidator (non-generic) for any validator.

Comment: @Sidewinder94 but if I use non-generic GetService() I still need to specify IValidator<Type>, still need to give the generic param there. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @fox112358 You missed @stuartd comment, which allows you to build up a `Type` with it's generic parameters "filled" at runtime

Comment: @MarioVernari it is designed to work with some complex types rather than string and something like string won't have any Validator<string> registered therefore it will be bypassed

Answer (score 3):

Use another overload of the `GetService` method.

Specifically the one having the following signature [`object? GetService(Type serviceType)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iserviceprovider.getservice?view=net-6.0)

Have all the methods you'll need to call into a non generic `IValidator` interface

Have your `IValidator<T>` interface extend the non generic one.

Then you can resolve with :

```
var validator = (IValidator)_serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IValidator<>).MakeGenericType(new[] { type }))
```